# WordPress query to get correct count number for an ACF fields?

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields, phpquery

First submission field (acf field) of the current post is empty .
So, the query should show 0, but it shows 1.
I tried following codes, and all of them show 1.
Would you please let me know how to get the correct count 0?

```
    $posts = array(
    'author'            => get_current_user_id(),
    'posts_per_page'    => -1,
    'post_title'        => get_the_title(),
    'post_type'         => 'infosubmission',
    'meta_query'        => array(
            array(
            'key'       => 'firstsubmission',
            'value'     => 'done'
        )
     )
  );

$post_b = new WP_Query( $posts );
$the_count = count($post_b); 
echo 'COUNT:' .$the_count;
```

```
$posts = get_posts(array(
    'author'            => get_current_user_id(),
    'posts_per_page'    => -1,
    'post_title'        => get_the_title(),
    'post_type'         => 'infosubmission',
    'meta_key'          => 'firstsubmission',
    'meta_value'        => 'done'
));

$the_query = new WP_Query( $posts );
$the_count = count($the_query); 
echo 'COUNT:' .$the_count;
```

```
$infopost = [
    'author'         => get_current_user_id(),
    'post_type'      => 'infosubmission',
    'posts_per_page' => -1, 
    'post_title'     => get_the_title(),
    'firstsubmission' => 'done'
];

$info_posts = new WP_Query($infopost);
$info_count = count($info_posts);   
echo 'COUNT:' .$info_count;
```

[image]

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

```
/* please replace below snippet in your code */

$posts = get_posts(array(
    'author'            => get_current_user_id(),
    'posts_per_page'    => -1,
    'post_title'        => get_the_title(),
    'post_type'         => 'infosubmission',
    'meta_key'          => 'firstsubmission',
    'meta_value'        => 'done',
    'meta_compare'   => '=' 

));
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for your help, but it still shows 1....